# Skip javascript snippet of code for crawlers

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-crawler, skip

I have a website in php, that pass certain php variables to javascript variables, google crawled me, which generates errors and duplicate content. Is there any way to make the google crawler to ignore the declaration of these variables in javascript?

```
    echo '<script language="javascript">var '.$item['Nombre'].'="'.$descripcion.'";</script>';
```

Sorry for my english,

Comment: Could you describe the way it "generates errors and duplicate content"? Are you using Webmaster Tools? Duplicate content usually means same content on different urls. Can you show us a few example urls where google found duplicate content? Are these parameters `GET` parameters per chance? I suspect that you misinterpreted the error.

Comment: Is a distribution brands page, each brand is loaded on a page like "/ firmas/1.html", "/ fimas/2.html" .. but all brands are loaded from the main page on javascript variables to display the content in a div, to make a onmouseover using innerHTML above brand names. This "onmouseover" is present in all brands, since it is part of the menu, so if you enter "/ firmas/1.html" load all variables as in index.html, but only displays wich has the id 1. Ideally used alone within <noscript> value for crawling.

Comment: I'm using Webmaster tools. But the problem is that google does not give me error, but google not indexes pages becouse considered to be the same content on every page.

Comment: Google does not give you an error? Then how do you know that it's "because considered to be the same content on every page"? After your description I would think that the problem is not "same content" but "no content". Google will not read your javascript. Also it is possible that I misinterpret something. Could you please edit your question, explain your scenario (how many pages are there, what contains what exactly) and include the relevant parts of your code (like what is actually happening on mouseover)? Your description in your comment is **very** ambiguous!

Comment: I've used 'languaje="javascript"'. I've changed by 'languaje="text/javascript"', and now I'm still waiting a new crawl from Google. I know it because on searchs on description shows var name description of each variable.

Comment: @halfer I know, SoonDead said me it below. Because this, I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google crawling javascript code and considering it duplicate? I have never heard of this problem before. Some of my pages have inlined javascript (if the content is small), that means the same `<script>...</script>` on every page.

There are also cases where I output javascript variables more-or-less the same way you do. Google never marked it as "duplicate content".

Description from [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en):

> Duplicate content generally refers to substantive blocks of content
>   within or across domains that either completely match other content or
>   are appreciably similar. Mostly, this is not deceptive in origin.
>   Examples of non-malicious duplicate content could include:
>
> - Discussion forums that can generate both regular and stripped-down pages targeted at mobile devices
> - Store items shown or linked via multiple distinct URLs
> - Printer-only versions of web pages

You can get this kind of errors if you have the same content on more than one of your pages, but google does not parse javascript as content. (Although you can never know for sure what google does or does not). The same way that google will not mark your `<head>` tag as duplicate, or there is no penalty for having the same layout (menu, footer, etc) on every page.

You can put that `<script>` tag in an [`<aside>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside) tag just to be sure.

> The HTML  Element represents a section of a page that consists
>   of content that is tangentially related to the content around it,
>   which could be considered separate from that content. Such sections
>   are often represented as sidebars or as inserts. They often contain
>   side explanations, like a glossary definition; more loosely related
>   stuff, like advertisements; the biography of the author; or in
>   web-applications, profile information or related blog links.

This means that the content will be more or less ignored by google when indexing the page. It will not mark it as a duplicate since it could be a commertial.

Also drop the `language="javascript"` attribute from your script tags. I doubt that it would confuse google in any way, since [that attribute is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) (use `type` instead) and nothing takes it into account nowadays. But if google bot does, the correct value would be `text/javascript` instead of simply `javascript`. It is possible that google does not recognise the value `javascript` and parses it as unknown type of text content.

The default type of the script is `text/javascript`, so it is **safe** to omit.

---

Above all I suspect that the problem is not the existence of JS variables, but some other thing like GET parameters in your URL. GET parameters can be dealt with by configuring URL Parameters correctly in Webmaster Tools.

Comment: Ok, I've used languaje="javascript", I will change it to see if this resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Important: This is bad practice in most of the cases. If google notices that you serve different content to it's bot and considers it relevant, than your site can get penalties beyond measure.**

**I do recommend this php solution**:

in PHP use this code:

```
if (!strpos($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’],"Googlebot")) {
  //echo the script
}
else{ //dont echo, does nothing. }
```

**But if this don't work you can try adding this javascript code into your script tag:**

```
    if (!navigator.userAgent.contains('Googlebot')) {
    //do the script
    } else {
    //does nothing
    }
```

Ps: Here is a list of User-Agents http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/

Comment: `Googlebot` is not the correct user agent string - see https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en

Comment: This is bad practice in most of the cases. If google notices that you serve different content to it's bot and considers it relevant, than your site can get penalties beyond measure.

Comment: @broofa sorry, i did a little mistake in js code, now it works :) and its now valid.

Comment: Are you sure this JS will actually work?  Specifically, is there any evidence that Google uses a JS runtime that specifies a detectable user agent?  That seems counter to what I expect is their primary goal: index the content a visitor will see when they visit the site.

Comment: @broofa well, maybe you're right but i think that a bot acts like a browser in "interpretate" terms, and maybe the errors caused by bad interpretation of the snippet of code. But is just a opinion.

Comment: @broofa by the way i see how the php solution is better after reading what you said. edited the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure either - but the userAgent presented by a spider-bot when it requests a page doesn't have to be the same as what a JS engine runs with.  And, in fact, I'm betting that Google has two separate systems in place - one for doing the crawl of static web page markup, and one for evaluating the dynamic [script] content a page may have.  I'm not sure there's any way of determining the behavior either, short of asking someone at Google. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Another (untested, speculative) approach that requires that you can write your own [`robots.txt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) file:

1. Move all your javascript code generation to another URL and include this as a javascript script in your page: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/my/php/that/generates/js/variables.php"></script>`
2. Add that URL to your robots.txt file (see [Google answer](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449))

> User-Agent: Googlebot
>
> Disallow: /path/to/my/php/that/generates/js/variables.php

Comment: Highly skeptical this will do what you claim.  While it will prevent your `variables.php` file from showing up in google searches, I'm willing to bet it won't prevent Google from using it as a script when indexing a different [allowed-by-robots.txt] web page that imports that script.

Comment: Yeah... so... there's that.  Which has me tempted to downvote. :-/  Probably best if you at least note that this is a speculative approach with untested behavior in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use following PHP code:

```
$crawlers = array(
'Google'=>'Google',
'MSN' => 'msnbot',
'Rambler'=>'Rambler',
'Yahoo'=> 'Yahoo',
'AbachoBOT'=> 'AbachoBOT',
'accoona'=> 'Accoona',
'AcoiRobot'=> 'AcoiRobot',
'ASPSeek'=> 'ASPSeek',
'CrocCrawler'=> 'CrocCrawler',
'Dumbot'=> 'Dumbot',
'FAST-WebCrawler'=> 'FAST-WebCrawler',
'GeonaBot'=> 'GeonaBot',
'Gigabot'=> 'Gigabot',
'Lycos spider'=> 'Lycos',
'MSRBOT'=> 'MSRBOT',
'Altavista robot'=> 'Scooter',
'AltaVista robot'=> 'Altavista',
'ID-Search Bot'=> 'IDBot',
'eStyle Bot'=> 'eStyle',
'Scrubby robot'=> 'Scrubby',
);

function crawlerDetect($USER_AGENT)
{
// to get crawlers string used in function uncomment it
// it is better to save it in string than use implode every time
// global $crawlers
// $crawlers_agents = implode('|',$crawlers);
$crawlers_agents = 'Google|msnbot|Rambler|Yahoo|AbachoBOT|accoona|AcioRobot|ASPSeek|CocoCrawler|Dumbot|FAST-WebCrawler|GeonaBot|Gigabot|Lycos|MSRBOT|Scooter|AltaVista|IDBot|eStyle|Scrubby';

if ( strpos($crawlers_agents , $USER_AGENT) === false )
   return false;
// crawler detected
// you can use it to return its name
/*
else {
                                                                                                                                                        1,1           Top
 return array_search($USER_AGENT, $crawlers);
}
*/
}
```

Using above method you can check Request is coming from crawler or not.